# Sites 9.1 how to clean up unnecessary data from State Store DB

Tags: deployer, sites-9.1

We upgraded from Sites 8.5 to Sites 9.1 and we noticed in some cases the items not getting cleared from the State Store DB. Can we clean up the data, if so what this the procedure?

Comment: Please can you provide more details on why the items are not getting removed from state store , do you see any error on the logs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to this [link](https://docs.sdl.com/783502/753349/sdl-tridion-sites-9-1/scheduling-a-periodic-cleanup-of-the-state-store-database) for more details on how to Scheduling a periodic cleanup of the State Store database

Comment: Thanks Shiva and Anand

Answer (score 1):

As Anand posted, you can schedule clean up of obsolete records from the state store database.

In upgrade scenarios, I would recommend the [following link](https://gateway.sdl.com/CommunityKnowledge?articleName=000010734) from the SDL KB article. There link details hotfixes, settings and the tuning information which might be useful to the issue that you are facing.

`delete from EXECUTION; delete from EXECUTION_PROPERTY; delete from PIPELINE; delete from STEP; COMMIT;`

The short answer to your question is to run something like the below on the state store database.